# Using Python on the shared Windows Gitlab runner

Tags: python, powershell, gitlab

[More than a year ago](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/01/21/windows-shared-runner-beta/) Gitlab announced a beta of shared runners for windows.

I would like to use this feature to bundle a Python application into an executable with `pyinstaller`, but I fail to get the most basic build environment. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
.shared_windows_runners:
  tags:
  - shared-windows
  - windows
  - windows-1809

build:
  extends:
  - .shared_windows_runners
  stage: build
  script:
  - wget.exe https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.4/python-3.9.4-amd64.exe
  - .\python-3.9.4-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1
  - $env:Path += "C:\Program Files\Python39\"
  - python.exe -m pip install .
  - python.exe -m pyinstaller my_app.py -F
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - my_app.exe
```

This fails at the `pip install` step with the following error message:

```
python.exe : The term 'python.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python.exe -m pip install .
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When I use this instead:

```yaml
script:
  - wget.exe https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.4/python-3.9.4-amd64.exe
  - .\python-3.9.4-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1
  - '"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" -m pip install .'
```

At least `python.exe` can be found (I guess) but the arguments are not taken as expected.

```
At line:1 char:40
+ "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" -m pip install .
+                                        ~~
Unexpected token '-m' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:43
+ "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" -m pip install .
+                                           ~~~
Unexpected token 'pip' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Can you give me some pointers how to correctly pass the arguments for PowerShell?

Comment: A string literal (like `"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"`) is just that - a string literal. If you want to _invoke_ it as a command, use the call operator `&`: `& "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" -m pip install .`

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies some things about powershell for me. After further experimenting, I now think that the installer does not work (i.e. does not install python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833355/5119485) has the solution. Python should be installed with `choco`.

For this case the correct `.gitlab-ci.yml` is this:

```yaml
.shared_windows_runners:
  tags:
  - shared-windows
  - windows
  - windows-1809

build:
  extends:
  - .shared_windows_runners
  stage: build
  script:
  - choco install python --version=3.9.4 -y -f
  - "C:\\Python39\\python.exe -m pip install ."
  - "C:\\Python39\\Scripts\\pyinstaller.exe my_app.py -F"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/my_app.exe
```